# Bash HEREDOC Single Quotes around expanded variable

Tags: bash, heredoc

I need the $table var to expand but while keeping the quotes that are required by MSSQL for the table_name parameter. I don't know if this is possible as I have been searching for a while. The common answer I see is if there are any quotes then variables won't be expanded. Is it simply not possible to do what I need here?

**Code**

```
cat <<EOF | isql $host sa 'password' -d, | sed '-e 1,10d;$d' | sort > mssql_table_${table}_column_info
use $database;
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$table';
EOF
```

**Desired Output**

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'mytable_name';
```

Notice that the output has single quotes still around the table name. This is necessary for MSSQL to select the appropriate table.

Comment: The `| isql ...` seems irrelevant to the question, and may be getting in the way of debugging.  If you just do `cat << EOF`, you should see that you are indeed getting the select statement that you want.

Comment: I just tried that and yes that worked. Thank you. So that would lead me to think it's maybe something with one of the other commands that happens?

Comment: Notice also that this is UUOC; you can do `isql << EOF "$host" sa ...`

Comment: I don't understand completely, but removing the UUOC made this work. If you can explain this in an answer so that I can mark this as solved I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Weird.  The `cat` shouldn't make any difference at all. Perhaps you made some other change when you took it out.

Comment: This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. Don't construct queries using string interpolation.

Comment: If someone is in the system to even try and use this.... wouldn't I have worse things to worry about? Seriously asking... I don't do security. This is outside of web root and behind an SSH Tunnel down to one IP address.

Comment: ...so we've ended up with a determination that the issue was non-reproducible, right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the variable expansion in the here document is the problem though? If you just inspect the output of the cat command (using bash):

```
$ database=database123 table=mytable_name cat <<EOF >/dev/stdout
   use $database;
   select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$table';
EOF
use database123;
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'mytable_name';
```

You might want to break down what the other commands are doing to make sure where the error is.

On a side note, your mention of turning off the variable expansion via quotation marks (' or ") apparently conflates the syntax of the here document with the unrelated syntax of other commands in the pipeline.

For example this is correct:

```
### works, prints 'hello hello'
MYVAR='hello' cat <<EOF | grep 'hello hello'
  hello $MYVAR
EOF
```

As opposed to:

```
### WRONG, response empty
MYVAR='hello' cat <<'EOF' | grep 'hello hello'
  hello $MYVAR
EOF
```

Does *not* perform the variable substitution, because the *word* `'EOF'` is quoted in the here document, turning off variable expansion. This is regardless of whether other commands in the pipeline, that is `grep 'hello hello'`, have quotes or not.